# Are SV5-5 spade connectors proprietary / trademarked?

Tags: connector, wire-terminals

I wish to advertise a product as using *SV5-5 forked terminals*. I am worried that I would be infringing someones trademark if I use the words "SV5-5 10AWG forked connectors"

Is it a generic standard? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search comes up with a large number of vendors selling SV-type terminals. SV seems to be vinyl insulated fork terminals and SB for instance is uninsulated. But where the terms originates from is unclear. You could just advertise the product as having fork terminals for 10AWG and indicate the spade size with a bolt size: #4-6 stud (US size) or whatever you need. That should be generic enough to not infringe on any trademark.

Answer (score 1):

In the USA the PTO (Patent and Trademark Office) maintains a database of registered trademarks.  That might be a good place to start.

[enter link description here](https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/search?MURL=SearchTrademarks)